# android is not recognized as an internal or external command [how to install android command]

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to convert Volley to a jar file. However a step in the guide has me input into the command prompt:

"android update project -p .

ant jar "

but I get that android is not a command. I have never used this command before today and the guide assumes that it is already on my system. Can someone explain how to install and use the "android" command

Comment: Which guide are you following?

Comment: The one here:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/
However I am having trouble because I do not know how to install android for use in the command prompt.

Comment: I was able to get the android command working but I get "missing argument for flag -p"

Comment: Post the code snippet.